# Service Creation in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.Can you let me know what's the problem in github.js service that i have created.
I keep getting the error 
**ReferenceError: github is not defined**

Here is the plunker link too
https://plnkr.co/edit/4jnawDJgdMM61GYfpxor?p=preview

```
(function() {







    var github = function($http) {

      var getuser = function(userName) {
        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + userName).then(
          function(response) {
            return response.data;
          });

      };


      var getRepos = function(user1) {
        $http.get(user1.repos_url).then(
          function(response) {
            return response.data;
          });

      };

      return {
        getuser: getuser,
        getRepos: getRepos

      };


    };


    var module = angular.module("MyTestApp");
    module.factory("github", github);


  }




)();
```

Comment: no it throws clear error .doesn't allow me to save the file

Comment: The answer solves your problem of referenceerror for github. Please accept the answer and extend the question for further support.

Comment: in the same thread or a separate new question?

Comment: Same thread or separate, as you wish, i would recommend separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not injected github service in your main controller.

Check the plunker: [Fixed typerror for github undefined](https://plnkr.co/edit/iMx5eb16hUr7Blgl95SF?p=preview)

```
function MainController($scope,$http,$interval, github) {
```

Here is the plunker with everything fixed: https://plnkr.co/edit/m6QoWh6UPpsgcAtsopSQ?p=preview

```
app.service('github', function($http) {
  this.getuser = function(userName) {
    return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + userName);

  };

  this.getRepos = function(user1) {
    return $http.get(user1.data.repos_url);

  };
});
```

Comment: Your fix doesn't  work .My code should behave like script2.js

Comment: The above solution fixes your referenceerror. There is issue with anpther function which is not relevant to this question. Accept the answer and extend the question with further error